Very large discrepancy between du and df
OS is Debian. I have a few systems that seem to not be freeing disk space correctly.
On a normal system:
du --max-depth 1 / --exclude=/proc -h -x

Seems to almost exactly agree with:
df -h /

ie, ~800 gigs are reported used in both cases for my normal system test case.
On an affected system, df shows 95 gigs used, but du only shows ~55 gigs used!
This is a huge discrepancy, especially compounded by the fact that the affected system also reports 0 bytes available for /.
lsof | grep deleted 

shows nothing. Filesystem is ext4.
What is going on here?
Edit: The issue ended up being a problem with lsof. To briefly summarize: running lsof without any parameters ended up taking so long (hours) that it appeared that nothing was getting returned, but I think lsof was just getting killed. Running lsof like this: lsof / | grep deleted was much, much faster, would exit correctly, and when doing so would show one very large deleted file. Running lsof / also excludes any other mount points, even if they are "inside" of /.

Maybe you have a directory on which something is mounted, so the contents are masked by the mount.

Are you running du as root or your normal account? Also, how many inodes are in use (df -i /)? You might also want to do an fsck to make sure that the filesystem isn't acting up.
